# A good size RAM-disk for Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hardware, server-administration

I'm running a Minecraft Craftbukkit server using this [awesome script](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init). My box has 3GB of RAM, and I have it set up to use 2GB minimum, and 2.5GB max.

I want to use the RAM-disk feature in the script, but I'm wondering how much space is needed for the RAM-disk to be effective? I've heard people get away with only using 200MB of RAM disk, and like 100MB of RAM for the server process, which seems sketchy...

Given I have 3GB of RAM available to me, any thoughts on RAM-disk size in comparison to just RAM?

P.S. Does this belong on Super User?

Comment: RAM - Random Access memory, the more you have, the smoother the sever will be...

Comment: Well, this is pretty general knowledge, if you want a good server just give the server all your ram, if you have 3gig ram left, then you might have a really laggy server if you plan on running Minecraft along with it. And if you are planning on playing a a server, then you probably are going to use Skype which will take up even more ram. It also depends on your processor, what type of processor do you have and is it dual/quad/single core? Servers also matter on internet connections. Also on the amount of people you plan on having on your server and what you are doing in it...

Comment: You're making a ton of assumptions which I don't think most people would agree with (Skype on a server doesn't even make sense). You also did not answer my question in any regard. Please consider re-reading my question, and try to keep with Stack Exchange guidelines with regards to constructive comments. I'm deleting my previous comment because it was not constructive, and I urge you to do the same.

Comment: For the world data on a small server, I would guess around 256 mb. More is always better, but that should suffice. If you're planning on making a big server, you should look at around a gigabyte or more. Don't forget to backup your world data, RAM disk is volatile and gets wiped on reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest maps I've ever downloaded have only just about topped 100MB. Unless you generate an obscene number of chunks, 200MB is going to be fine.

Comment: For downloadable maps yes, try running a public server though, the map size will grow to multiple gigabytes within weeks, if not days